# Server 10Gb connect in Switch 1Gb

Tags: networking, cable, fiber

I have a server that has 10Gb NIC and a switch with 1Gb SFP ports can I buy a 10Gb DAC cable at the 2 ends that will work? including the switch that is 1Gb? Or can I buy an LC-LC cable and a SFP+ connector to connect to the server and an SFP connector to connect to the switch?

Comment: i sont get the point how the text is written. As long the switch can obly 1Gbit and not GByte it does not make any sense.

Comment: As with all network: The highest speed across the network is determined by the slowest link between the two points. It doesn't matter that you have 10 gbps at both ends, if traffic goes through a link with 1 gbps. In that case the fastest speed will always be 1 gbps across the network.

Answer (score 0):

A 10G DAC won't work in a 1G SFP port.

Most likely, your 10G NIC is compatible with 1G SFPs, so get yourself two 1000BASE-SX transceivers compatible with the NIC and the switch respectively and connect them with a multi-mode fiber path cable.

Alternatively, you can use 1000BASE-LX transceivers and a single-mode patch. Depending on the exact compatibility of the NIC and the transceiver, an 10GBASE-SR SFP+ module might also link with a 1000BASE-SX SFP module in the switch (or 10GBASE-LR with 1000BASE-LX) - unless you're planning to upgrade your switch very soon it might just be more expensive though.